# Problem in first PHP program in RHEL 5.0 printing "hello world."

Tags: php, rhel5

I want to learn PHP in RHEL 5.0.

So for this I installed Apache server by

```
yum install httpd* 
service httpd restart
```

Then I wrote a simple program. At this time I am in `/root` directory

```
vi deepak.php
<?php

echo -e "Hello World This is my first program in Php";

?>
```

Then I went in GUI MODE and open Mozilla Firefox and in the address bar I gave address

> localhost/root/deepak.php

But this is not working for me.  The error is very common, `Server can not find the page..`

Now I think my coding is right, but I don't know where I am wrong.

Do I have to make some more settings in my RHEL or have to make some entry in any file?

Should I have to install PHP separately?  And if yes, please tell me correct package name for RHEL 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to make sure Apache & PHP are installed. As root:

```
yum install http php
service httpd restart
```

To see information and a list of files about the **php** package you just installed, type:

```
rpm -qil php
```

The **php** package pulls in the **php-cli** package, so you can now do this:

```
[user@box ~]$ php -v
PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Apr  7 2009 08:00:18)
Copyright (c) 1997-2006 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2006 Zend Technologies
[user@box ~]$
```

Next, you need to place your PHP files in the correct location. The default Apache location is:

```
/var/www/html
```

So, create /var/www/html/test.php as root, and it should work at http://localhost/test.php.

Developing applications/software as root is not advised. You should create a separate user for general usage and software development. See:

1. http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-5-manual/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-users-configui.html (or the useradd command)
2. /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf - find the UserDir section, and enable UserDirs as per the instructions. You'll need to restart apache (`service httpd restart` as above) after making changes. Enabling UserDirs will allow your newly created user to create a public_html directory in their home directory, and then have files accessible at http://localhost/~username.

The internet contains lots of documentation of varying quality and relevance, stick with the RHEL docs as much as you can.

good luck!